# jQuery sortable reorder

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-sortable

I have some structure:

```
li#lists
--ul
----li.category

------ul.due
--------li.item

------ul.date
--------li.item

------ul.other
--------li.item
--------li.item
--------li.item
```

I need to sord my li.item elements in ul.other element. Now in some category sorting is working, but i need sort items to another category.

Example: i need sort "This is sortable 2" after "This is sortable 5". or sort "This is sortable 5" after "This is sortable 2".

My code ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XYEtC/9/)):

```
$('.category ul.other').sortable({
    items: "li",
    helper: "clone",
    cursor: "move",
    placeholder: "drag-to",
    opacity: 0.5,
    connectWith: ".category ul.other"
}).disableSelection();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [bug #4551](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4551). The `connectWith` option apparently does not work as expected when the augmented list items are floated.

Removing `float: left;` from the following rule solves your problem at the expense of the item layout (you may want to specify a fixed width to compensate):

```
#lists .due li,
#lists .date li,
#lists .other li,
#lists .title {
    float: left;  // <-- Remove this style.
    padding: 8px;
    margin-left: -9px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    border-radius: 2px;
    margin-top: 1px;
}
```

You will find an updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/XYEtC/10/).